# Import DATA to SQL Server from CSV file

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a CSV file with 10 columns. I want to import to SQL Server table with only 5 columns using powershell. Can anyone help in this ?

Comment: can you provide detail on what you are unable to do? Have you tried anything?

Comment: you can use `import-csv` probably.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that Change your excel file to 5 sight column, and then using SQL Server Import\Export wizard or SSIS (if your convert is each day periodic) or PowerShell to convert your data.

You can you following reference in order to use PowerShell to convert your file:

[SQL SERVER – Powershell – Importing CSV File Into Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/27/sql-server-powershell-importing-csv-file-into-database-video/)